# Exception starting AntiSamyFilter

Tags: java, eclipse, filter, filenotfoundexception, antisamy

I'm unable to run my group's web application on my local machine with the AntiSamy filter in place. The filter works on WebSphere on our development and production servers, and also runs fine on one of my colleagues' machine with what should be the same setup as mine, using Tomcat. However, on my machine and several other colleagues', if we try to start our server with AntiSamy filter in place, we get this error:

Oct 12, 2015 11:06:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter AntiSamyFilter
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\myUsername\Documents\myWorkspaceDirectory.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\mobile3\WEB-INF\classes\antisamy-default.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

I've looked in the directory cited, and there is an "antisamy-default.xml" file there, so I'm not sure where to begin to figure out what's causing the error.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: How do you deploy your webapplication and how do you start it?

Comment: The issue occurs when running the webapplication locally. The workspace is set up in a Maven project for build. To run, we simply right click the server and say to start. The server is a Tomcat server.